# Server time zone wrong? Reservations +7 hours

Tags: php

I recently migrated a website from an old server to a new c-panel server on Godaddy. Previously reservations could be made for the same day, as long as it didn't begin before the current time. After migration, the site now rejects reservations made for same-day, and reservations that are made have a timestamp 7 hours ahead of actual time. I'm told by Godaddy that there is no way to change the server time zone on a shared hosting plan. I'm not a programmer. This is a site my dad built. He has passed and I'm just trying to keep it going for his loyal customer. I've learned a lot along the way but I'm hitting a wall on this one..

Would changing $NowTime=time(); to the applicable time zone fix it? Am I missing a function that is preventing reservations for the same day?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. Is there something I can do to make it readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the timezone you whish to use with [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

> Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script.

The argument is a string and has to be a [supported timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Comment: So if I change the following line from 
```
$NowTime=time();
```
to 
```
$NowTime=date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```
It will use that time zone instead of the the server time zone?

Comment: No. `date_default_timezone_set()` Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script. So you only should add `date_default_timezone_set("your timezone here");` at the begining of your PHP script. - Please read the provided documentation.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (green checkmark). ;)